# What is the best way to return different types of ResponseEntity in Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I would like to return two different response for a spring boot rest API.

I should not be using <?> wild card as i get the sonar issue **"Generic wildcard types should not be used in return types"**

My code:

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/v1/{type}"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> method(@PathVariable(value = "type")  boolean type) {
        boolean b = type;// some logic
        if (b) {
       
            Success result=new Success();
            result.setSuccess("Yes");
        
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            Error result=new Error();
            result.setError("No");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result,HttpStatus.CONFLICT); //appropriate error code
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to handle this situation.

**Update:**

```
    public interface MyResponse{
      public Success getSuccessObj();
      public Error getErrorObj();
    }
```

```
    @Service
    public class Success implements MyResponse {
     public Error getErrorObj(){
      return null;
    }
    public Success getSuccessObj(){
     Success s=new Success();
      return s;
    }
```

```
    @Service
    public class Error implements MyResponse {
     public Error getErrorObj(){
      Error e=new Error();
       return e;
     }
     public Success getSuccessObj(){
      return null;
     }
```

Comment: hi & welcome to [so]! For two (- not too many) response objects (assuming you can change them), you could use "inheritance"/define an interface/superclass for these 2 !?

Comment: i think the stackoverflow is due to:  `return new ...`, "try" instead: `return this;` ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not claiming to be "the best way", but one approach can be:

1. Introduce:

   ```
   package com.my.package;

   public interface MyResponseI { //if Error, Success (and others) have more "in common", you can also introduce an (abstract) class (with fields, methods, etc.)!
   }
   ```
2. "Implement"/Extend:

   ```
   public class Success implements com.my.package.MyResponseI { //everything else can stay}
   ```

   as

   ```
   public class Error implements com.my.package.MyResponseI { //everything else can stay}
   ```
3. Use as Response Type:

   ```
   @...
   public ResponseEntity<com.my.package.MyResponseI> ...
   ```
4. (on client side distinguish).

..and in "your domain" (error, success, ...), you are free to use any "tweaks" of a object oriented design.

---

Useful links/entries:

- https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/
- https://swagger.io/resources/articles/best-practices-in-api-design/
- https://www.google.com/search?q=rest+api+design
  , but also
- https://www.google.com/search?q=object+oriented+design
- and https://www.google.com/search?q=domain+driven+design

Comment: please review the above code.i get java stackoverflow exception when i use the above approach

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

I tried the snippet below by myself and it worked for me:

```
@GetMapping("/testresponse/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> testMyResponse(@PathVariable("id") int id)
{
    if(id==1)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Success());
    else return new ResponseEntity<>(new Error(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}

public class Success {
    private String msg = "Success";
    
    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
}

public class Error {
    private String msg = "Error";
    
    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: The solution as below doesn't work**

You should also define an interface for both Success and Error classes. Let say the interface MyResponse

And then change your method declaration, it would look like this

```
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> method(@PathVariable(value = "type")  boolean type)
```

If so, the return statement, could be:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Or

```
//for status 200 OK
return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
```

Comment: Howie S. Nguyen : please review the above code.i get java stackoverflow exception when i use the above approach.

Comment: Turn out, it's very simple at least for me. I've just updated my post above

Comment: Howie S. Nguyen :  I should not be using <?> wild card as i get the sonar issue "Generic wildcard types should not be used in return types"

Comment: @bkumon, it happened to the code you're showing above, didn't it?